# Setting up sbt to publish to artifactory based on git branch

Tags: git, sbt, artifactory, sbt-assembly

I would like to set up an sbt project so that it can publish to the proper artifactory repository based on the (git) branch.

The solution proposed for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33091153/can-sbt-publish-to-jfrog-artifactory) suggests to hardcode the repository in the build.sbt file.

However, I would like the master branch to publish to "releases", and another branch to publish to "snapshots", using the same build.sbt file.

Ideally, I would like the following:

```
val gitBranch = taskKey[String]("Determines current git branch")               
gitBranch := Process("git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD").lines.head 

publishTo := {                                                                 
  val myArtifactory = "http://some.where/"        
  if (gitBranch.value == "master")                                             
    Some("releases"  at myArtifactory + "releases")                              
  else                                                                         
    Some("snapshots" at myArtifactory + "snapshots")                             
}
```

but this yields "error: A setting cannot depend on a task".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One near-solution is to work with the `sbt-release` plugin, and then to use `isSnapshot` (which is a setting) in order to select the repository.

The solution to the original problem is to simply make `gitBranch` a setting:

```
val gitBranch = settingKey[String]("Determines current git branch")
```

instead of

```
val gitBranch = taskKey[String]("Determines current git branch")
```

Note that a setting is only computed once, at the beginning of the sbt session, so this is not suitable if there is any branch-switching within a session.

Thus, the whole code snippet will become:

```
val gitBranch = settingKey[String]("Determines current git branch")
gitBranch := Process("git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD").lineStream.head

publishTo := {                                                                 
  val myArtifactory = "http://some.where/"        
  if (gitBranch.value == "master")                                             
    Some("releases"  at myArtifactory + "releases")                              
  else                                                                         
    Some("snapshots" at myArtifactory + "snapshots")                             
}
```